# Bot Framework not working when connect with Azure Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created an Azure Bot. I have an echo bot running on my local machine.
I have exposed my bot using ngrok. It is running fine when I use the Bot Framework Emulator.

I entered my ngrok bot url on the Azure Bot Configuration tab. When I tested my bot in the Azure Bot webchat ("Test in Web Chat" tab), I see multiple calls on the "/" which are not handled.
What I am supposed to implement? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the actual path that your bot is expecting messages to come in on, and have you entered that in Azure? The samples and templates are all expecting messages to come in on `api/messages`.

So, in your Azure configuration, when you set your messaging endpoint to your ngrok endpoint, you need to append the path.

For example: `https://<your-ngrok-url>.ngrok.io/api/messages`. If you notice, in the emulator as well, you're typically connecting to `http://localhost:3978/api/messages`, not just `http://localhost:3978`.

Thus, if you just use `https://<your-ngrok-url>.ngrok.io`, your bot will never respond because it has no code that tells it what to do with requests on that endpoint.